# i am confused make this query to codeigniter - sum, distinct, join multiple conditions

Tags: codeigniter, join, sum, distinct, multiple-conditions

I have a correct mysql query but I am really confused to convert this to CI.
The result i want is just like this
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58lpJ.png)

```
select sum(distinct(tns.nilai)),tns.nis
from trs_nilai_sikap tns inner join trs_riwayat_nilai_sikap trns
on trns.id_tahun_ajar = 2
and tns.nis = 1800217
and trns.tipe_nilai = 1
and trns.id_riwayat_nilai_sikap = tns.id_riwayat_nilai_sikap
```

Comment: you can just pass your query to `$this->db->query($your_query)`

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems quite confusing in inner join.
Still i have tried in CI. Hope you get your answer.

```html
$this->db->select('SUM(distinct(tns.nilai)) AS total_nilai_sikap, tns.nis');
$this->db->from('trs_nilai_sikap tns');
$this->db->join('trs_riwayat_nilai_sikap trns', 'trns.id_riwayat_nilai_sikap = tns.id_riwayat_nilai_sikap', 'inner');
$this->db->where('trns.id_tahun_ajar', 2);
$this->db->where('tns.nis', 1800217);
$this->db->where('trns.tipe_nilai', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();
$query->result_array();
```